# How to decompose multiple periodicities present in the data without specifying the period?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, autocorrelation

I am trying to decompose the periodicities present in a signal into its individual components, to calculate their time-periods.

Say the following is my sample signal:

[image]

You can reproduce the signal using the following code:

```
t_week = np.linspace(1,480, 480)
t_weekend=np.linspace(1,192,192)
T=96 #Time Period
x_weekday = 10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t_week/T)+10
x_weekend = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t_weekend/T)+10
x_daily_weekly_sinu = np.concatenate((x_weekday, x_weekend)) 

#Creating the Signal
x_daily_weekly_long_sinu = np.concatenate((x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu))

#Visualization
plt.plot(x_daily_weekly_long_sinu)
plt.show()
```

My objective is to split this signal into 3 separate isolated component signals consisting of:

1. Days as period
2. Weekdays as period
3. Weekends as period

Periods as shown below:

[image]

I tried using the STL decomposition method from statsmodel:

```
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose()
```

But this is suitable only if you know the period beforehand. And is only applicable for decomposing a single period at a time.
While, I need to decompose any signal having multiple periodicities and whose periods are not known beforehand.

Can anyone please help how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried fourier transform?

Comment: @KonstantinZ yes, I've tried FFT. The ideal expectation would've been to see 3 distinct peaks as the output, but what I'm getting are multiple peaks. So it isn't helping.

Comment: @KonstantinZ I've in fact tried FFT and Autocorrelation as well. But they aren't giving desired results. Can you please check if you can improvise on these methods and apply it on the synthetic data above? (code shared in the question)

Comment: Yeah, you'll end up with octave harmonics on the daily response (i.e. 2, 4, 8 days) and subharmonics based on the Heaviside function you've basically implemented between weekday/weekend.  But the major peaks will still be apparent.  The only other option other than autoregression analysis (which will also show harmonics and subharmonics) is some homebrewed kernel regression, but I think you'll find that the kernels won't necessarily sort out to weekday/weekend as you like without putting your thumb on the scale even more than you would need to with `seasonal_decompose`.

Comment: FT is for sums of sinusoidal signals. That won't work here. The signal is a product of a sinusoidal function and periodic step functions. Before moving forward you need to get clarity what kind of signals you expect to decompose and what base functions they could be composed of. One example isn't enough.

Comment: You don't by any chance have more than one simultaneous output signal you're trying to decompose?  You might be able to use some sort of Independent Component Analysis (ICA) in that case.  But that doesn't work with only one output signal.

Comment: I think FT may be OK for this data, but you should not expect to see peaks in the wild. In any case, the peaks you would observe for this data is not related to 1, 2 & 3 from your plot, simply because they are not (perhaps except 1) the periods of your harmonic components.

Comment: @norok2 my objective is to identify the different periodicities present in the data. I've modified 2 & 3 in the figure to represent exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Joooeey my objective is to identify the different periodicities present in the data. It could be a signal having 1, 2, 3 or more no. of periodicities. It could be an activity representing eg. office temperature - where over weekdays you have a certain pattern in temperatures from morning to night, over weekends there's a certain pattern (due to non-occupancy), and over the course of the year there's fluctuations based on summer or winter. I need to identify the time period of occurrence of all these unique patterns, i.e. seasonality. Hence, this example I've provided is an apt representation.

Comment: Well you need to give some constraints, otherwise the possibilities are endless, you have too many degrees of freedom. Why do you insist on not knowing the periods? There's basically only daily, weekly and annual plus a long-term trend. Would you expect anything else? After you've come up with a model, you can still look at the residuals and see if another period jumps out that you might have missed. If you fix your periods, you can solve your problem by simple averaging.

Comment: So, your data is a piecewise defined periodic function, right? Then decomposing it with FFT without knowing the 'outer' period doesn't make sense. I experimented a little bit with seasonal_decompose and fft-ifft and can say that by playing with *period* of seasonal_decompose you can gain some information. So, please, give more constrains regarding your question: do you have any idea what are periods 2=3 on your exemplar figure? Is the function piecewise-defined within this period?

Comment: @Joooeey that's what's the issue: my actual situation's data could comprise of any number of periodicities and which may not just be a daily, weekly or annual period. In this sample dataset, I know exactly what the periods are. But I'd only created this dataset for testing purposes in order to check if I can use an appropriate robust algorithm to detect the periodicities in the data without having me enter the value of the same as input arguments. But looks like I'm bound by the fact that I've to know the periodicities beforehand. So, can anything be done to detect unknown periods?

Comment: @KonstantinZ as mentioned in my comment above, no I don't have info on what could the periods in the data be beforehand. That, exactly's what I would like to have as an outcome of this process. My actual dataset could have any number of periods present. Autocorrelation does produce repetitive units having patterns representative of different periods, but I haven't found a way to non-manually identify them. FFT has a lot of noise signals as output. And seasonal_decompose is limited by knowing the periods beforehand. So what could I possibly do to identify periods?

Comment: @EnigmAI That's why I asked for more examples. You need to know what kind of data you're dealing with and make some assumptions before you think about what's the best algorithm. Otherwise there's an infinite number of ways to construct that signal. Is there an upper bound on how many distinct signals there can be? What are the base signals? Is there noise?  For instance the assumptions for FT are that the signal is the sum of as many sinusoidal base signals as there are datapoints. But your example also includes step signals...

Comment: I think a derivative of the Fourier transform, like the STFT or the Gabor transform should give you clearer peaks. Auto-detecting the period would be a step after that though, these two tend to increase the data size. A bit like the 'chord' example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_analysis_for_music_signals

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried more of an algorithmic approach? We could first try to identify the changes in the signal, either amplitude or frequency. Identify all threshold points where there is a major change, with some epsilon, and then do FFT on that window.

Here was my approach:

1. I found that the DWT with Daubechies wavelet was really good at this. There are distinct peaks when transformed for when either one changes, which makes identifying the windows really nice.
2. Did a Gaussian mixture, to essentially key in on 2 specific window sizes. In your example, this is fixed but with real data, it might not be.
3. Looped back through pairs of peaks applied FFT and found prominent frequency.
4. Now you have the width of windows which you can use to identify from Gaussian mixture with another epsilon to figure out the period between windows, and FFT to have the prominent frequency within that window. Although, if I were you I would use the mixture model to identify the key frequencies or amplitudes in the windows. If we can assume your frequencies/amplitudes in the real world are normally distributed.

Note there are many ways you could mess with this. I would say starting with a wavelet transform, personally, is a good start.

Here is the code, try adding some Gaussian noise or other variability to test it out. You see the more noise the higher your min epsilon for DWT will need to be so you do need to tune some of it.

```py
import pywt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
data = x_daily_weekly_long_sinu
times = np.linspace(0, len(data), len(data))
SAMPLING_RATE = len(data) / len(times)  # needed for frequency calc (number of discrete times / time interval) in this case it's 1
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(data, 'db4', mode='periodization')  # Daubechies wavelet good for changes in freq

# find peaks, with db4 good indicator of changes in frequencies, greater than some arbitrary value (you'll have to find by possibly plotting plt.plot(cD))
EPSILON = 0.02
peaks = (np.where(np.abs(cD) > EPSILON)[0] * 2)  # since cD (detailed coef) is len(x) / 2 only true for periodization mode
peaks = [0] + peaks.tolist() + [len(data) -1 ]  # always add start and end as beginning of windows

# iterate through peak pairs
if len(peaks) < 2:
    print('No peaks found...')
    exit(0)

# iterate through the "paired" windows
MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH = 10   # min width for the start of a new window
peak_starts = []
for i in range(len(peaks) - 1):
    s_ind, e_ind = peaks[i], peaks[i + 1]
    if len(peak_starts) > 0 and (s_ind - peak_starts[-1]) < MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH:
        continue  # not wide enough
    peak_starts.append(s_ind)

# calculate the sequential differences between windows
# essentially giving us how wide they are
seq_dist = np.array([t - s for s, t in zip(peak_starts, peak_starts[1:])])

# since peak windows might not be exact in the real world let's make a gaussian mixture
# you're assuming how many different windows there are here)
# with this assumption we're going to assume 2 different kinds of windows
WINDOW_NUM = 2
gmm = GaussianMixture(WINDOW_NUM).fit(seq_dist.reshape(-1, 1))
window_widths = [float(m) for m in gmm.means_]

# for example we would assume this prints (using your example of 2 different window types)
weekday_width, weekend_width = list(sorted(window_widths))
print('Weekday Width, Weekend Width', weekday_width, weekend_width)  # prints 191.9 and 479.59

# now we can process peak pairs with their respective windows
# we specify a padding which essentially will remove edge data which might overlap with another window (we really only care about the frequency)
freq_data = {}
PADDING = 3  # add padding to remove edge elements
WIDTH_EPSILON = 5  # make sure the window found is within the width found in gaussian mixture (to remove other small/large windows with noise)
T2_data = []
T3_data = []
for s, t in zip(peak_starts, peak_starts[1:]):
    width = t - s
    passed = False
    for testw in window_widths:
        if abs(testw - width) < WIDTH_EPSILON:
            passed = True
            break
    
    # weird window ignore it
    if not passed:
        continue

    # for your example let's populate T2 data
    if (width - weekday_width) < WIDTH_EPSILON:
        T2_data.append(s)  # append start
    elif (width - weekend_width) < WIDTH_EPSILON:
        T3_data.append(s)

    # append main frequency in window
    window = data[s + PADDING: t - PADDING]

    # get domininant frequency
    fft = np.real(np.fft.fft(window))
    fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(window))
    freq = SAMPLING_RATE * fftfreq[np.argmax(np.abs(fft[1:])) + 1]  # ignore constant (shifting) freq 0
    freq_data[int(testw)] = np.abs(freq)

print('T2 = ', np.mean([t - s for s, t in zip(T2_data, T2_data[1:])]))
print('T3 = ', np.mean([t - s for s, t in zip(T3_data, T3_data[1:])]))
print('Frequency data', freq_data)

# convert to periods
period_data = {}
for w in freq_data.keys():
    period_data[w] = 1.0 / freq_data[w]

print('Period data', period_data)
```

With your example that printed the following (note results weren't exact).

```
Weekday Width, Weekend Width 191.99999999999997 479.5999999999999
T2 =  672.0
T3 =  671.5555555555555
Frequency data {479: 0.010548523206751054, 191: 0.010752688172043012}
Period data {479: 94.8, 191: 92.99999999999999}
```

Note this is what the DWT coefs look like.
[image: DWT Coefs]

Comment: @EnigmAI did you end up getting it to work?

Comment: So sorry for the delay in responding! This is working well for the exact example I've given. But when I add in a new set of periods along with the existing ones, with another amplitude (just like "t_week" & "t_weekend") like for eg.: t_weekx=np.linspace(1,288,288) #3 days, even then I would like to have the time periods identified. Can anything be done to identify that? Basically it needs to be generic to identify any no. of distinct periods present in the data.

Comment: Any updates regarding the query I've posted above?

Comment: @EnigmAI that is going to be pretty difficult. The only thing I could say you could try is looking at the DWT coefficients. You'll see during different changes of amp/freq how the coefficients change, and if you're certain that the frequencies between different windows are REALLY similar (ie frequency/amplitude for weekdays always stays about the same for each window) then you could try to identify them with DWT in a generic way. Each peak will look different and you could use a histogram of peak height to identify peaks within a certain epsilon. Again, uber generic like that is not easy.

Comment: Also, @EnigmAI this method will work if you already know how many no. of distinct windows (off different sizes) if you mess with WINDOW_NUM.